# CI MY Loader Error

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to use a custom function in MY Loader parent construct area called `DIR_TEMPLATE` But it is not picking it up.

**Error:** `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\codeigniter-cms\catalog\core\MY_Loader.php on line 14`

I am wanting to be able to do something like this in **controller**.

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . 'default' . '/template/common/header.tpl')) {
  return $this->load->view('default' . '/template/common/header.tpl', $data);
} else {
  return $this->load->view('default/template/common/header.tpl', $data);
}
```

**MY_Loader.php**

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH ."third_party/hmvc/loader.php";

class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH . 'views/theme/' => TRUE);
        $this->_ci_ob_level  = ob_get_level();
        $this->_ci_library_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
        $this->_ci_helper_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
        $this->_ci_model_paths = array(APPPATH);

        DIR_TEMPLATE = $this->_ci_view_paths; // Error Here
        $this->_ci_view_paths = DIR_TEMPLATE; // Not working

        Severity: Notice

        Message: Use of undefined constant DIR_TEMPLATE - assumed 'DIR_TEMPLATE'

        Filename: core/MY_Loader.php

        Line Number: 14


        log_message('debug', "MY_Loader Class Initialized");
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define `DIR_TEMPLATE`

```
 DIR_TEMPLATE = $this->_ci_view_paths; // Error Here
```

should be something like

```
define( 'DIR_TEMPLATE',  $this->_ci_view_paths );
```

**EDIT** :
since its an `array`
you cant not define it as a `PHP constant` as it supports `scalar and null only`

you can use

```
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', serialize($this->_ci_view_paths));
```

and when ever you need it you can just `unserialize()`

Comment: Getting 2 errors now. 
`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Constants may only evaluate to scalar values

Filename: core/MY_Loader.php

Line Number: 14`
`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant DIR_TEMPLATE - assumed 'DIR_TEMPLATE'`

Filename: common/header.php
Line Number: 38`

Comment: @user3659372 to define a constant it should be `int, float, or string` you are getting that error since its an array.

Comment: you mean like the way the index.php application is dir are.

Comment: @user3659372 check updated answer use `serialize()` and when ever you need you can `unserialize()` and use it

Comment: `problem loading page.` is not CI or PHP error. its connectivity issue. @user3659372

Comment: It loads a blank white page now. but file location is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56572/discussion-between-karan-thakkar-and-user3659372).

Comment: Problem Is Now Solved.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out now. I had do modify the define part of My Loader but all good.

**Loaded On Controller**

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE .'default' . '/template/common/header.tpl')) {
  return $this->load->view('default' . '/template/common/header.tpl', $data);
} else {
  return $this->load->view('default/template/common/header.tpl', $data);
}
```

**MY Loader.php**

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH ."third_party/hmvc/loader.php";

class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader {

    public function __construct() {
        define('DIR_TEMPLATE', APPPATH . 'views/theme/');
      $this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH . 'views/theme/' => TRUE);
      $this->_ci_ob_level  = ob_get_level();
        $this->_ci_library_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
      $this->_ci_helper_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
      log_message('debug', "MY_Loader Class Initialized");
   }  
}
```